# Language options: what is the use of "main=french" in the \documentclass command?

Tags: babel, languages, options, documentclass

If using the option `english,french` with babel and `french` in the `\documentclass` command, the following  warning results.

> Package babel Warning: Last declared language option is "french", but the last processed one was "english". The main language cannot be set as both a global and a package option. Use "main=french" as option.

The effect of this error is to change the output of varioref `\vref` commands from French to English; removing `french` from the `\documentclass` command or replacing it by `main=french` (as indicated in the warning), makes things right (no more warning, output all right).

What is the use of `main=french` when there is already `english,french` in the option brackets for babel? The default language is French when `english,french` has been chosen with babel and I suppose that “default language” is the same as “main language”.

Comment: class options are passed to packages, so babel sees "french,english,french" and finds this confusing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Interesting point, but wouldn't you have a few more indications concerning "main=french"?

Comment: with main=french you are telling babel exactly which language should be the main language and so it doesn't have to guess what "french,english,french" means.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But the order "english-first french-second" in the babel option does that, since the default when this order is used is "french".

Comment: you have `french-first english-second french-third`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I understand a little better now, thank you.